# Java OAuthClient other than Apache Oltu

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, oauth-2.0

I'm working on Spring Boot based application. I got already implemented OAuth Client via Apache Oltu which sends custom `OAuthClientRequest` and gets response as `OAuthAccessTokenResponse`. I was looking for that kind of library as it was in Apache Oltu but I get overwhelmed by number of Spring libraries and I don't really know what kind of Spring or Java library is made for that kind of work.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure I fully understand your scenario but the open source [Connect2id / Nimbus](https://connect2id.com/products/nimbus-oauth-openid-connect-sdk/guides/java-cookbook-for-openid-connect-public-clients) libraries are respected, with excellent documentation.

Answer (score 0):

Two possibilities come to mind:

(1) SpringBoot natively supports OAuth:

https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current-SNAPSHOT/reference/htmlsingle/#web.security.oauth2

Some examples you can find [here](https://spring.io/guides/tutorials/spring-boot-oauth2/).

> All samples are implemented using the native OAuth 2.0 support in Spring Boot.

(2) [scribejava](https://github.com/scribejava/scribejava) a simple OAuth client Java lib